# ABCPdf: Error converting powerpoint

Tags: .net, powerpoint, abcpdf

Does anybody knows, why ABCPdf gets an error, while converting an powerpoint-document to a pdf-document?

Stacktrace:

> ----> System.Exception : Error opening document
>   'C:\BuildServer\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c28da44c7c8be65\Tests\ePunkt.Tests.FileServer\bin\Debug\TestDocuments\OpenDocumentPowerPoint.odp'.
>   ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   ---->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Unspecified error
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))    at
>   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.XReadOptions.Read(Doc doc, String path)    at
>   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.Read(String path, XReadOptions options)

Comment: Solution:

Install Office Feature "Visual Basic for Applications"